# How to separate Numbers from string and move them to next column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am working on a share market data and in some columns market cap has shifted to previous column. I am trying to fetch them in next column but the value it's returning is completely different.

[image]

This is the code I am using -

```
data['Market Cap (Crores)']=data['Sub-Sector'].astype('str').str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().fillna('').sum(axis=1).astype(int)
data['Market Cap (Crores)']
```

But the output I am getting is

```
968             NaN
969             NaN
970   -2.147484e+09
971   -2.147484e+09
972   -2.147484e+09
```

How do I get the correct values?

Comment: What you need to do, of course, is go back to the source material and figure out WHY it is being parsed incorrectly.  Fix it BEFORE it goes into pandas.  Don't try to patch it up later.

Comment: there are around 10,000 records like this, and I have to do it through pandas only, I am facing this issue while solving a college assignment. So, I've got to solve it through Python only :(
Any suggestions How to correct it?@TimRoberts

Comment: why are you using that code? for starters, those don't look like ints to me! It looks like you're extracting all text elements that look like they might possibly be interpreted as integers (including e.g. both sides of the decimal point in a float as two separate ints), and then summing them? It would be helpful to understand more about the structure of the data and exactly what you're trying to extract. Is it always a single float number at the end of the Sub-Sector column?

Comment: Yes, it's a float number that's always there at the end of the Sub-Sector column .

Comment: Is this being read from a CSV? are the attributes in the read command correct? I would verify whether the data actually looks this way in the original file if you have it, or if the read into Pandas is mismatching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do it, step by step.  First, pick out the rows that need fixing (where the market cap is Nan).  Then, I create two functions, one to pull the market cap from the string, one to remove the market cap.  I use `apply` to fix up the rows, and substitute the values into the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['GNA Axles Ltd', 'Auto Parts', 1138.846797],
    ['Andhra Paper Ltd', 'Paper Products', 1135.434614],
    ['Tarc', 'Real Estate 1134.645409',  np.NaN],
    ['Udaipur Cement Works', 'Cement 1133.531734', np.NaN],
    ['Pnb Gifts', 'Investment Banking 1130.463641', np.NaN],
]

def getprice(row):
    return float(row['Sub-Sector'].split()[-1])

def removeprice(row):
    return ' '.join(row['Sub-Sector'].split()[:-1])

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns= ['Company','Sub-Sector','Market Cap (Crores)'] )
print(df)

picks = df['Market Cap (Crores)'].isna()
rows = df[picks]
print(rows)

df.loc[picks,'Sub-Sector'] = rows.apply(removeprice, axis=1)
df.loc[picks,'Market Cap (Crores)'] = rows.apply(getprice, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Company                      Sub-Sector  Market Cap (Crores)
0         GNA Axles Ltd                      Auto Parts          1138.846797
1      Andhra Paper Ltd                  Paper Products          1135.434614
2                  Tarc         Real Estate 1134.645409                  NaN
3  Udaipur Cement Works              Cement 1133.531734                  NaN
4             Pnb Gifts  Investment Banking 1130.463641                  NaN
                Company                      Sub-Sector  Market Cap (Crores)
2                  Tarc         Real Estate 1134.645409                  NaN
3  Udaipur Cement Works              Cement 1133.531734                  NaN
4             Pnb Gifts  Investment Banking 1130.463641                  NaN
                Company          Sub-Sector  Market Cap (Crores)
0         GNA Axles Ltd          Auto Parts          1138.846797
1      Andhra Paper Ltd      Paper Products          1135.434614
2                  Tarc         Real Estate          1134.645409
3  Udaipur Cement Works              Cement          1133.531734
4             Pnb Gifts  Investment Banking          1130.463641
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Sub-Sector Number'] = df['Sub-Sector'].astype('str').str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack().fillna('').sum(axis=1).astype(int)
df['Sub-Sector final'] = df[['Sub-Sector Number','Sub-Sector']].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
df
```

Hi there,

Here is the method which you can try, use your code to create a numeric field and select non-missing value from Sub-Sector Number and Sub-Sector creating your final field - Sub-Sector final

Please try it and if not working please let me know

Thanks Leon